# Protect PDFs from edition as when scaned

Tags: windows, pdf-generation

Protect a pdf with a password is not secure, because you can break easily this protection. I want to avoid that someone takes my sign (attached as picture) from my signed PDFs.

To do this, I'm printing the document, and after printed I'm scaning to my computer. In this scanned document you will not able to copy and paste the attached sign.

Do you know a software able to do this withouth the need of print and scan the document? (Microsoft windows)

Thank you in advance
I have installed Adobe acrobat pro.